# How to make image FILL the ancestor widget using photo_view

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a carousel of images that are zoomable using the photo_view library. The problem is when I try to define a size for the parent widget, the photo_view maintains the image proportion when setting the minScale to contained.

There is any way to achieve this?

obs: Setting minScale to covered doesn't work because it zooms the image and affects the page scroll gesture on the page.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .7,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: carousel(),
    );
  }

  Widget carousel() {
    return PhotoViewGallery.builder(
      pageController: pageController,
      scrollPhysics: disableGesture
          ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
          : BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: images.length,
      onPageChanged: (i) => callback(i),
      builder: (BuildContext context, int index) => PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
        scaleStateCycle: (scaleState) => scaleState,
        disableGestures: disableGesture,
        minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
        maxScale: 5.0,
        basePosition: Alignment.topCenter,
        imageProvider: FileImage(File(images[index].path)),
      ),
      loadingBuilder: (context, event) =>
          Center(child: CircularLoading(20, 20, 4, Colors.red)),
      backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[300]),
    );
  }
```